# how to add taxonomy terms to admin/config/people/accounts/fields programmatically?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, users

I know I can use the UI at `admin/config/people/accounts/fields` to add existing taxonomy fields.

But I want to create them automatically using my module.

I know I can use `hook_enable()` or `hook_install()` for this but I don't know which hook or function I need to use to make the field show up in `admin/config/people/accounts/fields` ( and on the user edit / registration page )

I've read somewhere something about a bundle but I'm not sure if I'm looking in the right direction there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the field, and then attach it to your content type. This is done using the [`field_create_instance()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_create_instance/7) function.

There's a nice example in the standard profile of attaching the 'Tags' vocabulary to the article content type upon install:

```
$instance = array(
  'field_name' => 'field_' . $vocabulary->machine_name,
  'entity_type' => 'node',
  'label' => 'Tags',
  'bundle' => 'article',
  'description' => $vocabulary->help,
  'widget' => array(
    'type' => 'taxonomy_autocomplete',
    'weight' => -4,
  ),
  'display' => array(
    'default' => array(
      'type' => 'taxonomy_term_reference_link',
      'weight' => 10,
    ),
    'teaser' => array(
      'type' => 'taxonomy_term_reference_link',
      'weight' => 10,
    ),
  ),
);
field_create_instance($instance);
```

The documentation page has a full list of all the available properties for your field instance, but the above code is an excellent place to start.

I also have this piece of code in my arsenal which dumps the field/instance definitions of an existing field so I can inspect it and just chop and change what I need to:

```
$entity_type = 'node';
$field_name = 'field_FIELDNAME';
$bundle_name = 'BUNDLE_NAME';

$info_config = field_info_field($field_name);
$info_instance = field_info_instance($entity_type, $field_name, $bundle_name);
unset($info_config['id']);
unset($info_instance['id'], $info_instance['field_id']);
include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/utility.inc';
$output = "field_create_field(" . drupal_var_export($info_config) . ");\n";
$output .= "field_create_instance(" . drupal_var_export($info_instance) . ");";
drupal_set_message("<textarea rows=30 style=\"width: 100%;\">". $output .'</textarea>');
```

Comment: so in this case ( adding it to a user ) the bundle_name should be `users` ?

Comment: It's just `user` (without the `s`). The bundle's defined in [`user_entity_info()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_entity_info/7) in case you're interested

Comment: turns out that my vocabulary machine name wasn't the same as the field_name causing errors and not creating the instance.
thanks for showing this answer so I could check that it wasn't the code that was wrong :)